# Добавление логотипа с подписью в Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Для удобства привожу скриншот плагина elementor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно вставить логотип

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а под ним надпись Мир Цифровой Электроники вместо элемента

```
                                                Это заголовок
              Проснувшись однажды утром после беспокойного сна, Грегор Замза обнаружил, что он у себя в постеле превратился в страшное насекомое,
```

либо логотип может быть любым элементом, стоящем выше блока

```
                                            Перетащите виджет
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставьте элемент "Изображение"

Вставьте элемент "Заголовок"

Удалить ненужные элементы со страницы