# Устранение ненужного отступа

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Сделал согласно [Добавление логотипа с подписью в Elementor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176575/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b2-elementor) и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом устранить ненужный отступ?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5c403f745f7b8900aaf231c4/kak-v-plagine-elementor-ubrat-nijnii-otstup-v-blokah-5cc9d3543e66cc00af04ae9e . Необходимо в инструментах разработчика в браузере изменить padding у соответствующего элемента.

P. S. Поскольку не хватает места в комментариях, то привожу замечание (если не так что-то отредактируйте) - @IgorR. вот например в отличие от [Отображение сайта в WordPress и Elementor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176650/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-wordpress-%d0%b8-elementor) этот запрос [Удаление отступов в Elementor](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk01cSztk2sOtWFfNwcvkc_RqyRAT_g%3A1599743635864&ei=kyZaX6esNOWMwPAPmqauoAc&q=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%20elementor&oq=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%20elementor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6CQghEAoQoAEQKjoHCCEQChCgAVCJqhBYqdYQYO7ZEGgBcAF4AIAB3gGIAZ8RkgEGNy4xMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjnwZa51d7rAhVlBhAIHRqTC3QQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) дает ответ на поверхности, но не по каждой теме можно получить такой ответ (это ответ на замечание на [Отображение сайта в WordPress и Elementor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176650/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-wordpress-%d0%b8-elementor)).