# Сохранение css-стилей в файле style.css WordPress-а

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Пытался отредактировать файл с целью устранения отступов ([Устранение ненужного отступа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176683/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0)) и нашел соответствующие классы с нужным `padding` (их оказалось 3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body.elementor-page-7 {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
section {
  padding 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.elementor-column-gap-default>.elementor-row>.elementor-column>.elementor-element-populated {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body class="page-template page-template-elementor_canvas page page-id-7 logged-in admin-bar wp-custom-logo wp-embed-responsive singular enable-search-modal missing-post-thumbnail has-no-pagination not-showing-comments show-avatars elementor_canvas footer-top-visible elementor-default elementor-template-canvas elementor-kit-9 elementor-page elementor-page-7 customize-support" data-elementor-device-mode="mobile">
<section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-8014c8f elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="8014c8f" data-element_type="section">
<div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
```

Отредактировал в Инструментах разработчика значение 3-х padding-ов, а также соответствующие файлы `.css`. Но после редактирования обновлял страницу и логотип становился на прежнее до редактирования css файлов место. Подскажите как сохранить измененные значения padding-ов.

Создал файл functions.php и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб расширить функциональность темы - нужно создать дочернюю тему в директории `wp-content/themes`/ создать папку `{имя_активной_темы}-child`

Например, если активная тема twentyten, то создать папку `twentyten-child,` и в ней создать файлы `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 11);
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('td-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', '1.0.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('td-theme-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('td-theme'), '1.0.1', 'all' );

}
```

и `style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name:     {имя_активной_темы} Child
Theme URI:      #
Description:    {имя_активной_темы} Child
Author:         
Author URI:     
Template:       {имя_активной_темы}
Version:        0.1.0
*/
body.elementor-page-7 {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
section {
  padding 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.elementor-column-gap-default>.elementor-row>.elementor-column>.elementor-element-populated {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Тогда при обновление темы Ваши изменения сохранятся

Подробнее тут https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 0):

**Добавлено:
Данное решение имеет недостаток — при обновлении темы ваши изменения слетят. Чтобы этого избежать, необходимо использовать дочернюю тему.**

Инструменты разработчика не сохраняют результаты изменений. Для редактирования файла style.css вам надо либо подключиться к сайту по FTP/SFTP/SSH и найти его в папке с темой:

```
{публичная директория сайта}/wp-content/themes/{имя темы}/style.css
```

Также можно отредактировать этот файл через админку WP:

```
Внешний вид - Редактор Тем - выбрать справа файл style.css
```

Comment: Поправка по второму - не "этот файл"! И вообще не файл. Это **добавление** инлайновых стилей. Они хранятся в базе.

Comment: @SeVlad я специально проверил сейчас на одном сайте. Редактирование кода на этой странице физически меняет файл.

Comment: А, блин. да, это я не правильно рассмотрел твой ответ. Чой-то показалось что ты про кастомайзер (кстати стоит про него добавить в ответ). Виноват, каюсь :)

Comment: нельзя так делать. это изменение слетит при первом же обновление темы

Comment: Я бы таки смотрел в сторону создания дочерней темы и указания своих стилей уже в ней.

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev вы совершенно правы, я сторонние темы в WP не использовал больше 8 лет, поэтому забыл про это напрочь)

Comment: @Dzorogh не слетят если использовать кастомайзер. Напиши же про него в ответе. Без этого он не полный. К тому же в данном конкретном случае у ТСа самписная тема и ему дочка не нужна.