# Редактирование в Инструментах разработчика

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, elementor

Открыл **Страницы=>Все страницы**, а затем **Редактировать в Elementor** для **Elementor #7**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отредактировал. Затем для **Elementor #7** щелкнул **Перейти**. В открывающейся странице открыл **Дополнительные инструменты=>Инструменты разработчика**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отредактировал css файлы:

1. в данном случае

```css
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

(margin у body) в другом случае (как в [Сохранение css-стилей в файле style.css WordPress-а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176747/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-css-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-style-css-wordpress-%d0%b0) ) - padding-и в трех стилях;

в-третьем случае:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем вообще закрываю браузер и открываю Elementor (по ссылке **Перейти**) и ввижу прежний рисунок до редактирования.

Каким образом сохранить сделанные изменения в сss файлах, чтобы они сработали (и страница отобразилась с учетом указанных изменений) - хочу чтобы логотип оказался в левом верхнем углу?

P.S. Пытался сделать как на [Редактирование в Инструментах разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176933/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) с помощью дочерней темы, но в результате появлялась ошибка с functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

> Отредактировал css файлы:

где именно отредактировал, в инструментах разработчика? (в Google Chrome dev tools)

Отвечая на вопрос в заголовке: Редактировать в инструментах разработчика, можно только для себя, там есть трюки, позволяющие твоим изменениям сохраняться между обновлениями страницы, но это всё ещё только на твоей машине и только для тебя.

в момент когда ты открываешь страницу, wordpress формирует страницу на основе данных из базы и файлов на сервере - никакие инмения сделанные в твоём браузере, на это никак не повлияют.

Чтобы измения сохранились, нужно делать их на сервере:

- если редактировать исходные файлы, то надо следовать совету с дочерней темой, и разбираться с "возникающими ошибками в functions.php"
- Но большинство задач можно решить оставаясь в админке Wordpress, если всё, что требуется, это немного изменить стили, то их можно вставить в custom.css, большинство тем предоставляют такой файл, и доступ к нему в настройках Wordpress.
- Либо ещё можешь попробовать нажать "Изменить" вместо "Перейти", и в
  открвшемся окне, в тело страницы, добавить тег  (только там есть два режима ввода содержимого страницы, нужен "сырой" вариант, где таги видны, а не тот, где видно выделенную жирность и прочие стили текста)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<style>
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: как отрыть сырой вариант в третьем пункте (`Изменить`  и далее куда)?

Comment: для конструктора Elementor - никак, можете попробовать отключить его, тогда появится, но вот дальнейшая работоспособность - под вопросом(и отображение и обратное редактирование в Elementor).