# Добавление новой страницы

Tags: wordpress, интерфейс, elementor

Открыл пункт меню **`Страницы`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Щелкнул на кнопку **`Добавить новую`** (рядом с надписью страницы) и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо того что хотел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860661/auto-generated-page-file/63869575?noredirect=1#comment112944552_63869575 или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как на [Редактирование в Инструментах разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176933/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (как у Арсена Сиреканяна). Подскажите как добиться требуемого отображения.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас на скринах разные режимы.

На первом -  режим добавление новой страницы.

На втором - режим редактирование страницы.

Естественно ссылка в режиме добавление новой страницы не сформирована, т.к. не введен еще заголовок. После сохранения страницы Вы сможете править значение slug ссылки страницы

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что данные со страницы `http://digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/` и их разметка зависит только от моей базы данных `mainelectro`, а slug ссылка мне никак не поможет при редактировании страницы `http://digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/`? Файлы `page.php`, `page-{slug}.php`, `page-{id}.php`, `content.php` и прочие не содержат  кода со страницы `http://digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/`.

Comment: шаблоны содержат общую обвязку страницы. содержимое страницы в базе.