# Файл стилей, соответствующий user agent stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка, elementor

Хочу убрать желтую рамку вокруг логотипа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(смотри в правой боковой колонке - стиль body). Его свойства выделяются, но не удаляются (в инструментах разработчика chrome), а в каком из css файлов этот стиль находится не указано, а написано - `user agent stylesheet`. Каким образом можно обнулить `margin` у `body`?

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

PS: Даже не знаю, как этот ответ до 30 символов увеличить.

Comment: можно код обернут в сниппет, будет сколько надо ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy а в какой файл и в какое место файла нужно добавить стиль body ? (это понятно, что ваш код обнуляет margin. вопрос в том, куда его вставить - см. вопрос)

Comment: @Qwertiy вместо адреса файла css стилей написано `user agent stylesheet` (см. скриншот).

Comment: @programmerdev, да он в любом сработает. А уж куда там в вёрдпрессе принято распихивать стили, я понятия не имею.

Answer (score 1):

user agent stylesheet - это стили браузера

Вам нужно создать дочерний файл стилей для темы, чтоб их переопределить как описано тут [Сохранение css-стилей в файле style.css WordPress-а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176747/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-css-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-style-css-wordpress-%d0%b0/1176782#1176782)